# Reportlab - How to add margin between Tables?

Tags: python, reportlab

So i am trying to create three tables per page, the following code will collide all three tables together with 0 margin between them. I would like some white space between two tables. Is there a configuration for that?

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("my.pdf", pagesize=A4)
elements = []
i = 0
for person in persons:
    data = get_data()
    t = Table(data, colWidths=col_widths, rowHeights=row_heights)
    elements.append(t)
    i = i + 1
    if i % 3 == 0:
        elements.append(PageBreak())

doc.build(elements)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `Spacer` function to add space between the tables. An example of its use from the [documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) is:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer

def go():
 doc = SimpleDocTemplate("hello.pdf")
 Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]

 for i in range(100):
     bogustext = ("This is Paragraph number %s. " % i) *20
     p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
     Story.append(p)
     Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
     doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages)
```